# web scraping price zero problem from a site

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hi I want to grab prices from this code

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
list3 = []
r = requests.get('https://bama.ir/car/peugeot/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
res2 = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'listdata'})
for item in res2:
    z = re.findall(r'<span itemprop="price" content="([^"]*)">[^<]*</span>',str(item))
    list3 += z

for item in list3:
    print(item)
```

but this code not return "0" prices.I want "0" prices too.
can someone help me?

Comment: Based on your regex none of the prices are `0`

Comment: how can i add a zero to this regex?

Comment: `[^"]` already accounts for zero. It is a negated set which translates to "find everything which is not a double quote" and zero is not a double quote. The regex is correct but none of your `item`s contain zero.

Comment: some of my items are "0".and this regex doesnt show the "0"

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally use this code for getting numbers with zero

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
list3 = []
r = requests.get('https://bama.ir/car/peugeot/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
res2 = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'overview'})
for item in res2:
    z1 = re.findall(r'content="([0-9])"',str(item))
    list3 += z1
    z2 = re.findall(r'<!-- <p class="cost"><span itemprop="price" content="(\d*)">',str(item))
    list3 += z2
for item in list3:
    print(item)
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you'd wish to return the `0`s in the `content` attributes, which probably, this might be close:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
list3 = []
r = requests.get('https://bama.ir/car/peugeot/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
res2 = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'listdata'})
# print(res2)
for item in res2:
    z = re.findall(r'content="(\d*)"', str(item))
    list3 += z

for item in list3:
    print(item)
```

#### Output

```
145000000
145000000
77000000
77000000
0
116000000
116000000
106000000
106000000
105000000
105000000
0
58000000
3600000
0
0
142800000
142800000
35000000
35000000
0
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nWhTgj/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/nWhTgj/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Would it not be cleaner to simply extract the content attribute with dictionary syntax?

Comment: [i['content'] for i in soup.select('.listdata[content]')]

Comment: nothing wrong with answers I have seen of yours and the explanations are excellent. Was just a thought.